# Java thread creation tracking

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, threadpool, centos5

I have a java app with a heavy focus on concurrency and on burstable capacity. This means it uses thread pools to queue and execute events.

All these thread pools are fixed-size, but I constantly find myself bumping up against open file descriptor limits when the app is deployed on the Linux (CentOS 5.5) server.

To my count, the app, when under load, shouldn't create more than 20 threads at any one time, but I'm hitting a `ulimit` of 1024.

Is there any way I can track these threads back to the code/pool that created them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A sane thread pool should (at least optionally) allow the name to be specified.

For the normal [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) you need to implement a [`ThreadFactory`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) that names the threads appropriately. Then use [`setThreadFactory()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setThreadFactory%28java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory%29) to make it use your implementation.

You can also use the [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) [`ThreadFactoryBuilder`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ThreadFactoryBuilder.html) and call [`setNameFormat()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ThreadFactoryBuilder.html#setNameFormat%28java.lang.String%29) to get that functionality pre-built:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor myExecutor = ...;
ThreadFactory tf = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("myExecutorThread-%d").build();
myExecutor.setThreadFactory(tf);
```

Comment: Very useful, thanks. I created a simple `ThreadFactory` which took a name as its constructor and narrowed down the issue to a third-party library which used an unbounded, and lazily, if ever, reclaimed thread pool.